# Android sound record problem

Tags: android, audio

I'm trying to record sound on android, using code basically just copied from the developer docs, here it is:

```
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

I get a runtime exception on the 4th line, I@m not sure why. Could you help?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace here?

Comment: are you running this on an emulator?

Comment: Whoops, I've answered it, I forgot to add the record sound permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top tip:
 - Always check you've given your app the appropriate permissions! I forgot to let my app record sound.

Comment: Do you mean permission: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

Comment: Yes, I think that was the one. Thanks!